# flutter MaterialIcons-Regular.otf error when building apk

Tags: flutter, dart, apk

im trying to build the apk but im getting a

Failed to load input font

C:\Users....\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\material_fonts\MaterialIcons-Regular.otf; aborting. This error indicates that the font is invalid or the current version of Harfbuzz is unable to process it.
tried checking the previous answers but saddly nothing worked for me

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * Where:
    Script 'C:\Users\.....\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
    > Process 'command 'C:\Users\...\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    
    * Try:
    > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
    > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    > Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 1m 28s
    Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           91.1s
    Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded it from here [here](https://github.com/mono0926/flutter-animations/blob/main/docs/assets/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.otf) and I created a font directory and added the icon manually. Then in `pubspec.yaml` just add

```
fonts:
- family: MaterialIcons
  fonts:
    - asset: fonts/MaterialIcons-Regul
```